# Can not click checkbox with element from by.repeater

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

For some reason I can not click a checkbox with `by.repeater`. There are no errors. When viewing the browser, the checkbox is simply not getting checked. Any ideas? I would like to stay with `by.repeater` if possible.

```
  this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models'));
  } 

  checkboxes.modelChoices().get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIVEN:

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group" ng-repeat="item in vm.dataFiles | filter:vm.query">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked">
        </span>
        <label class="form-control">{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is part of my e2e tests that might help you in a way.
Note that I have my checkbox bound to "item.isChecked"

```
it("should disable the create button when there are no checked items in the vm.dataFiles", function () {
    var dataFiles = element.all(by.repeater("item in vm.dataFiles"));
    var firstCheckbox = dataFiles.get(0).element(by.model("item.isChecked"));
    var btnCreate = element(by.id("btnCreate"));

    expect(btnCreate.isEnabled()).not.toBeTruthy();
    firstCheckbox.click();
    expect(btnCreate.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
    firstCheckbox.click();
    expect(btnCreate.isEnabled()).not.toBeTruthy();
});
```